# UIBarButtonItem flexibleSpace does NOT WORK

Tags: xcode, swift4

From iOS 11, the UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace does not work.

My source code:

```
let backupBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "itemRate.png"),
                                    style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain,
                                    target: self,
                                    action: #selector(goToBackup))

let sortBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "itemSize.png"),
                                  style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain,
                                  target: self,
                                  action: #selector(changeSort))

let sizeBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "itemSize.png"),
                                  style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain,
                                  target: self,
                                  action: #selector(changeSize))

let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace,
                                target: nil,
                                action: nil)

self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([sizeBtn, space, sortBtn, space, backupBtn], animated: true)
```

It does not matter if I use:

- self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems
- self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems

Buttons appear on left side or right side, **but always together!!!**

Comment: It works for me when used on a UIToolbar, I don't think it should work on NavBar!

Answer (score 0):

**The lame solution!**

You can use this solution on left side or right side, as you want:

```
let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

space.width = (self.view.frame.size.width/2) - (40*UIScreen.main.scale)

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backupBtn

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [sortBtn, space, sizeBtn]
```

**Horrible, I Know!**